Custom sound not working in Android notifications
I can't get my app to play a custom sound in its notifications. It always plays the default notification sound instead. This is my class for posting notifications:
class AndroidNotificationCentre(private val context: Context): NotificationCentre {
    private val notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(context)
    private val soundUri = uriOfResource(R.raw.gcalert)
    private val audioAttributes = AudioAttributes.Builder()
        .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_NOTIFICATION)
        .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SONIFICATION)
        .build()

    fun createChannels() {
        Log.d(TAG, "Creating notification channels with sound '$soundUri'")
        createChannel(
            AngelNotificationChannel.OWN_SAFETY,
            "Your Safety",
            "Get alerts when your own safety status changes",
            NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH
        )
        createChannel(
            AngelNotificationChannel.OTHER_SAFETY,
            "Friends' Safety",
            "Get alerts when your friends' safety status changes",
            NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH
        )
        createChannel(
            AngelNotificationChannel.GROUP_MEMBERSHIP,
            "Group Membership",
            "Get alerts when others leave or join your group",
            NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT
        )
        createChannel(
            AngelNotificationChannel.LOCATION_REQUEST,
            "Location Request",
            "Receive notifications when the server needs to know your location",
            NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH
        )
    }

    private fun createChannel(
        id: AngelNotificationChannel,
        name: String,
        description: String,
        importance: Int
    ) {
        val builder = NotificationChannelCompat.Builder(channelIds[id.ordinal], importance)
            .setName(name)
            .setDescription(description)
            .setSound(soundUri, audioAttributes)
            .setVibrationEnabled(true)
        val channel = builder.build()
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
    }

    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    fun postFirebaseNotification(remoteNotification: Notification) {
        val intent = Intent(context, MainActivity::class.java)
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)
        val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
            context,
            0, /* Request code */
            intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE,
        )

        val channelId = (remoteNotification.channelId ?: "").let {
            if (channelIds.contains(it)) {
                it
            } else {
                val desc = if (it.isEmpty()) "null" else "'$it'"
                Log.e(
                    TAG,
                    "Unknown channel $desc in Firebase message, using 'own_safety'")
                "own_safety"
            }
        }

        Log.d(TAG, "Posting notification with " +
                "body ${remoteNotification.body}, channel $channelId")
        val builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(context, channelId)
            .setContentTitle(remoteNotification.title ?: "Message from Group Companion")
            .setContentText(remoteNotification.body ?: "No message body")
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notif_sm)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setSound(soundUri)

        val notification = builder.build()
        val tag = remoteNotification.tag
        val id = tag?.let { 2 } ?: nextId++
        try {
            notificationManager.notify(tag, id, notification)
        } catch (e: Throwable) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Notification error: ", e)
        }
    }

    fun uriOfResource(resId: Int): Uri {
        val res = context.resources
        val uri = "${ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE}://" +
                "${res.getResourcePackageName(resId)}/" +
                "${res.getResourceTypeName(resId)}/" +
                res.getResourceEntryName(resId)
        return Uri.parse(uri)
    }

    companion object {
        val channelIds = arrayOf(
            "own_safety",
            "other_safety",
            "group_membership",
            "location_request",
        )

        private var nextId = 3

        const val TAG = "angelNotifs"
    }
}


The actual filename of the sound effect is gcalert.wav and I noticed that the generated URI does not include the .wav. I tried adding it explicitly and it still didn't work. I've also tried using "${R.raw.gcalert}" instead of "${res.getResourceTypeName(resId)}/" + res.getResourceEntryName(resId) but that doesn't work either.
